# Merge two Matplotlib plots having different ranges for the Y-Axis into one plot such that the shapes of the individual plots remain the same

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to put my two plots into one plot without changing their shape. They have a very different y range.
Here are my two plots (I get them when I run the corresponding line of code for the plot) :

Plot 1:

[image: Plot 1]

Plot 2:

[image: Plot 2]

When I try plotting both of them onto the same graph, I get :

Plot 3:

[image: Plot 3]

The plots end up losing their original shape. I'm assuming this is happening because the ranges of y used in both the plots is not the same.
These are the data values I used to plot :

```
y1 = [3.3549674089380157, 3.3549674741748685, 3.354967474135432, 3.3549674741683244, 3.354967802849705] 
y2 = [2.273429505964899, 2.273429556154414, 2.2734295561240736, 2.2734295561482813, 2.2734297980416596]
x = [-16.0, -13.0, -10.0, -6.0, -2.0]
```

Comment: This looks like a typical use case for `twinx`. See e.g. the following tutorial example: [Plots with different scales](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-two-scales-py)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ax.twinx()` to create a secondary Y-axis on the right-hand side, then plot each line independently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-16.0, -13.0, -10.0, -6.0, -2.0]
y1 = [3.3549674089380157, 3.3549674741748685, 3.354967474135432, 3.3549674741683244, 3.354967802849705]
y2 = [2.273429505964899, 2.273429556154414, 2.2734295561240736, 2.2734295561482813, 2.2734297980416596]

fig, ax_left = plt.subplots()
ax_left.plot(x, y1, label='y1', color='green')
ax_left.set_ylabel('y1')

ax_right = ax_left.twinx()
ax_right.plot(x, y2, label='y2', color='orange')
ax_right.set_ylabel('y2')

plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Note that since both lines have basically the same shape, they overlap when plotted individually on each axis - but both lines are there with their "original" shape preserved. I've tried to make this a bit clearer by using different colors and labeling each Y-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it be possible to use a single Y-axis for both the plots so that there would be a gap between them?

Comment: You can do this by breaking the Y-axis in a specific point, although that's not as straightforward. Take a look at this example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html.

Comment: This might be what i need, thank you!